# Which sutra explains how to form any habits.?

Tags: meditation

It's a sutra to do meditation/ any task for like around 24 hours. I don't remember exactly which it is. But I remember it's half translation in English. ( it say.first Do task/meditation 1x time and  relaxation 1x . Then. (I don't remember exactly but. Cut out relaxation time in some pattern and some more lines were there.  And last this is a way to meditate/ do any task for 24 hours.